# Movie or TV show where a man drowns himself in a lake to plug a hole while a woman feeds him grapes

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

I am trying to figure out where a scene came from, either a movie or TV show, in a medieval setting, where a man is sacrificing himself in a lake to plug a hole that would otherwise drain the lake. The woman he is doing this for, some kind of princess, is feeding him grapes into his mouth.

I think I saw it around 1990-1995. This is a childhood memory, so some of the details could be off.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The story is George MacDonald's "[The Light Princess](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/697/697-h/697-h.htm)". Definitely fantasy. According to IMDB the BBC made [a TV movie about it](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0229533/) in 1978.

Here is part of that scene from the original story:

> So the water grew and grew, and rose up and up on the prince. And the
>   princess sat and looked at him. She fed him now and then. The night
>   wore on. The waters rose and rose. The moon rose likewise higher and
>   higher, and shone full on the face of the dying prince. The water was
>   up to his neck.
>
> "Will you kiss me, princess?" said he, feebly.
>
> The nonchalance was all gone now.
>
> "Yes, I will," answered the princess, and kissed him with a long,
>   sweet, cold kiss.
>
> "Now," said he, with a sigh of content, "I die happy."
>
> He did not speak again. The princess gave him some wine for the last
>   time: he was past eating. Then she sat down again, and looked at him.
>   The water rose and rose. It touched his chin. It touched his lower
>   lip. It touched between his lips. He shut them hard to keep it out.
>   The princess began to feel strange. It touched his upper lip. He
>   breathed through his nostrils. The princess looked wild. It covered
>   his nostrils. Her eyes looked scared, and shone strange in the
>   moonlight. His head fell back; the water closed over it, and the
>   bubbles of his last breath bubbled up through the water. The princess
>   gave a shriek, and sprang into the lake.

Comment: Appreciate your help!